# Determinant of random matrix nearly always zero

Tags: java, matrix, random

Hello and happy new year.

I implemented a matrix class, and one static method is to create a random matrix.

It's fairly simple and seems to work

```
public static Matrix random(int m, int n)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Matrix rndMatrix = new Matrix(m, n);
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            rndMatrix.setEntry(Math.random(), i, j);
        }
    }
    return rndMatrix;
}
```

The members of a matrix object are the various methods, 2 integers that represent number of rows and columns, and a double[][] that represents the data.

I also implemented a method that calculates the determinant of a given matrix.

It's rather complex but this is the code

```
public double determinant() throws RuntimeException // Via Gauss elimination. O(n^3)
{
    int m, n;
    double det = 1;
    m = this.getDimensions()[0];
    n = this.getDimensions()[1];

    if(m != n) // not a square matrix
    {
        System.out.println("determinant given non square matrix");
        RuntimeException e = new RuntimeException();
        throw e;
    }

    Matrix copy = new Matrix(this); // work on a copy, don't change original

    for(int i = 0; i < m-1; i++) // pivot row (and column) is i
    {
        double maxPivot = Math.abs(copy.getEntry(i, i));
        int maxPivotRow = i;
        for(int j = 1; j < m; j++) // perform partial pivoting for numerical stability
        {
            double potentialPivot = copy.getEntry(j, i);
            if(Math.abs(potentialPivot) > maxPivot)
            {
                maxPivot = potentialPivot;
                maxPivotRow = j;
            }
        } //now our pivot is at copy[maxPivotRow][i]

        if(maxPivotRow != i) //need to swap rows
        {
            det *= -1; //each row swap changes sign of determinant

            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) //change row i and row maxPivotRow. j runs on columns
            {
                double temp = copy.getEntry(i, j);
                copy.setEntry(copy.getEntry(maxPivotRow, j), i, j);
                copy.setEntry(temp, maxPivotRow, j);
            } // now our pivot is at copy[i][i]
        }

        if(copy.getEntry(i, i) == 0) //Pivot is 0, meaning determinant is 0
            return det;

        for(int j = i + 1; j < m; j++) // rank!
        {
            double coefficient = copy.getEntry(j, i) / copy.getEntry(i, i);
            for(int k = i; k < m; k++)
            {
                double currentElement = copy.getEntry(j, k);
                copy.setEntry(currentElement - coefficient * copy.getEntry(i, k), j, k);
            }
        } 
    }// copy is now row reduced, upper triangular. determinant is product of diagonal

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        det *= copy.getEntry(i, i);
    }

    return det;
}
```

the calculation is done via gaussian elimination (with partial pivoting) and then multiplying the elements on the diagonal. I have tested it several times and it seems to work.

the problem is that it doesn't work on random matrices, or well, I'm getting an unexpected behavior.

9 out of 10 times i'll create a random matrix and calculate its determinant, it will print 0.0 or -0.0.

This seems odd. "Most" matrices are invertible. So why does this happen? Is there a bug? Do I not understand the math?

**Edit: A few examples (number on bottom is the determinant**

```
0.9563941736946711 0.39448005321813573 0.5470486104302432 0.5261160742874216 0.3951820646725023 
0.7346088704461295 0.7599880918925735 0.8497744950194082 0.8867153096935724 0.3682481741589534 
0.9263551689754832 0.2317726305104606 0.18178575740374336 0.07986150434799666 0.7819470135579004 
0.1745757641530633 0.25563633619467996 0.2829688806860611 0.5118728924839205 0.03297040489736147 
0.25186307283907405 0.9562803829692509 0.483921593496489 0.8755617387463226 0.31088898779219853 
0.0

0.00891316485803817 0.713796166860513 0.13287589794651955 0.4064378440682588 0.4978814476005716 
0.12055412802144772 0.972471867370921 0.53095134849769 0.22189312703335484 0.8817515464656179 
0.9315367039854036 0.6438575977028148 0.43392574349285307 0.08726203670701893 0.6130528522290233 
0.9643660752404595 0.3691976358204304 0.340490090444587 0.5684232640065617 0.0628244760775013 
0.15365612075823543 0.3168819918400785 0.6665980934501206 0.02089370959057013 0.6078409694254645 
-0.0

0.9621768497790205 0.8676421360459282 0.4465279858313177 0.48320978463573283 0.5439303840591143 
0.09762305323682163 0.42529504824730524 0.7969529998650778 0.5061554064144165 0.4140523901347064 
0.003060974877453826 0.5969505627805348 0.5322677244514962 0.5667640313747856 0.9861085023353954 
0.3615427851315477 0.6472381774117999 0.9852641653717541 0.2397370854247155 0.7528175137110793 
0.5143296881839451 0.020615097451925468 0.24636629586280845 0.39986298958960864 0.7414827709198659 
6.393441112567584E-18
```

However when I create a random 3 by 3 matrix:

```
0.6791409154789895 0.9015085022510533 0.9674292726638446 
0.9059154025420992 0.26610950783426457 0.08492267434013878 
0.6974770770379765 0.4474657891394087 0.12363906335455344 
0.16156349092473768

0.1048566480579386 0.5949449637931188 0.28220872314980017 
0.6303444427050728 0.17136149490672603 0.7630494228097563 
0.010042979011053998 0.4443731402226164 0.44005633657936627 
-0.10955506568102251

0.7080008734798865 0.7058454701623011 0.6520827337491946 
0.10322829578835746 0.7757507432730788 0.3650950541868936 
0.2742422959683706 0.9949312192553693 0.05039578697883251 
-0.23425225979344966
```

Comment: You may want to create a test which calculates the determinant on a given matrix where you know the result to see if your code works correctly.

Comment: I have, several times. It seems to work. Up to small numerical error. It seems as if all the random matrices I am generating really are not invertible. Is there any way to generate a random invertible matrix?

Comment: Could you be calling you random matrix generator with m!=n?

Comment: Why do you create a variable `Random r` and not use it?

Comment: Sorry about the Random r thing. I did use it to generate gaussian distributed numbers, but when that didn't work i moved to Math.random for testing. That didn't work either. I merely forgot to edit the code.

Comment: @kabanus nope. I'm calling it with a 50 by 50 random matrix.

Comment: @OriaGruber *""Most" matrices are invertible."* No, thats false. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix - with random values your matrix is only invertible by accident.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle actually you linked to proof that that's true. "Singular matrices are rare in the sense that a square matrix randomly selected from a continuous uniform distribution on its entries will almost never be singular."

Comment: Could you make this test a few times on 3x3 matrices, and if you still get these result post a couple of this random matrices?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle The set of singular matrices is of zero measure. it makes sense that singular matrices will be rare. ALSO - It seems to work very well on random matrices of size 3 and 4. But on 5 I'm getting determinant 0 much more frequently. and 6 more then that etc...

Comment: @OriaGruber Post a couple of 6x6 matrices with 0 determinant, so we can see easily if the problem is with the generation or the calculation.

Comment: @kabanus It's done.

Comment: @samgak m and n are the same so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @OriaGruber I'm getting 0.0143 for first matrix using numpy (which is will established). You probably have a subtle bug if I had to guess.

Comment: Could it be a numerical error?

Comment: Definitely - I suggest following your calculation with a debugger. Especially if there are x - (x_epsilon) type calculations. Or printing it if you dislike debuggers. Try and work on smaller matrices if possible.